# Prove that the upper and lower integrals, noted below in R^d...

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that the upper and lower integrals, noted below in R^d, do not depend on the choice of rectangle R as long as it contains E
[image]

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with upper and lower sums on ${\mathbb R}$ for the first time one proves (for several  kinds of limits) that $\int_a^b+\int_b^c=\int_a^c$ if $a<b<c$. This principle at once generalizes to the $d$-dimensional situation.

Let $R_1$ and $R_2$ be two rectangles $\supset E$ used to compute the integrals in the question. Find an even larger rectangle $R$ containing both of them.

The $2d$ face hyperplanes defining $R_1$ partition $R$ into $3^d$ subrectangles, only one of them, namely $R_1$, containing points of $E$. In all of the others $x\mapsto \chi_E(x)$ is identically zero. It follows that  your integrals computed for $R_1$ and for $R$ have the same value, and similarly the integrals computed for $R_2$ and $R$ have the same value.

Comment: Thank you.  Can this be proved directly from the definitions?

Comment: Thank you for your help :)